# MySQL: Query to get all rows from highest month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "accounts" and it has two fields "month" and "amount". I like to get highest month records to display front page

```
eg:

month amount

10/2013 -> 12
12/2013 -> 20
12/2013 -> 21
11/2013 -> 10
```

how could i filter highest month all data , I used **time stamp format** to store date

Comment: like in above table you need `21` amount row ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman indeed i need 21, and 20 amount rows

Comment: Highest month = last month in order?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE month = (SELECT MAX(month) FROM accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY month DESC

may work.

Comment: but how to stop query after display highest month data

Comment: You can user select max(month) from TABLE;